# Use data annotation to create comma separated number

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I am using the following data annotation and my goal is display a comma separated number in the UI.

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
 public double ItemSubTotal { get; set; }
```

Here's the view code:

```
<fieldset>
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Order.ItemSubTotal, Model.Order.ItemSubTotal.ToString())                  
</fieldset>
```

However I am not getting a comma separated result. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want a comma as the decimal separator?  If so that's culture specific.

Comment: No, I want to separate my number with comma. So If I have 120000, it should be 120,000.

Comment: I'm guessing you shouldn't do the `ToString` then so the formatter you specify will be used.  Otherwise it's trying to apply a number format to a `string`.